# Django-Admin.py in Powershell

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell

I think I'm encountering a weird bug in Windows 8.1 trying to use `django-admin.py` (and any script really) in Powershell. I've successfully installed Python 2.7.6, and have added `C:\Python27\` and `C:\Python27\Scripts` to my path.

When I try to use `django-admin.py` or `python django-admin.py` in Powershell, I get a file not found error.

Interestingly, when I use Command Prompt, I *am* able to use `django-admin.py`, even without the python prefix.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot?

Comment: Did you restart your shell after adding the directory to your path? Can you echo your path to the console?

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/esstp5.png

Comment: PATH variable: http://i59.tinypic.com/v5bcip.png

Answer (score 0):

To execute scripts in Powershell, you need to set the execution policy to something other than restricted. For example:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

This should allow general scripts (like .ps1 files) to be run. I still had problems running python files from the path so I added .py files to the PATHEXT variable. In Powershell:

```
$env:PATHEXT += ";.py"
```

I don't think this is permanent, so you may need to add it to your profile or change the environmental variables from the Advanced System Settings. This fixed the problem for me.